# Hover style of label in googleVis

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, googlevis

I'm trying to change the style of hover-label in googleVis columnChart. I'd like to format large numbers as it is done on axis. Do you know how to manage it (I've read whole Internet and still don't know how to fix it :D)?

The illustration of my problem (red is the format I have and green that I'd like to have):
[image]

And shiny-app example:

ui.R:

```
library("shiny")
library("googleVis")

shinyUI(fluidPage(

    htmlOutput("wyk")

))
```

and server.R:

```
library("shiny")
library("googleVis")
library("dplyr")

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    d <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(ile=1e6*sum(Sepal.Length))

    output$wyk <- renderGvis({

      gvisBarChart(d, xvar = "Species", yvar = "ile",
                      options=list(legend="top", bar="{groupWidth:'90%'}", height=500))

    })

})
```

Comment: In essence you want to separate every third number from the next with a space?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, yes, that's right.

Comment: This is probably more of a javascript question.Let's see if anyone familiar with googlevis API can chip in how to format numbers for labels, the way one can do it to format text in a gvisTable.

Comment: Yeah - I'm aware of that. The problem is that I don't know javascript at all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an extra column variable with the text you want to display and pass a vector of y-variables, giving the label aame ending in ".tooltip".  The tooltip can be styled with html tags.  `format` with `big.mark` can add commas in R.

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    d <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(ile=1e6*sum(Sepal.Length))
  d$ile.tooltip <- sprintf("<p><b>%s</b><br/><b>%s</b></p>", 
    d$Species, format(d$ile, big.mark=","))

  output$wyk <- renderGvis({
    gvisBarChart(d, xvar = "Species", yvar = c("ile", "ile.tooltip"),
      options=list(legend="top", 
        tooltip="{isHtml:'True'}",  # so you can format it with html
        bar="{groupWidth:'90%'}", height=500))
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks! It's not that pretty as the automatic one, but it can probably be changed using html.