# Format tooltip in googleVis

Tags: javascript, r, tooltip, shiny, googlevis

I would like to format number (add `big.mark`) in `tooltip` in `googleVis` chart. Yesterday I asked this quesion: [Hover style of label in googleVis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36125419/hover-style-of-label-in-googlevis) and got the answer. Today, I've got quite simillar problem - the difference is that there are more than one group, so adding `tooltip` does not work...

The visualisation of my problem: 
[image]

And my code:

`ui.R`:

```
library("shiny")
library("googleVis")

shinyUI(fluidPage(

    htmlOutput("wyk")

))
```

and `server.R`:

```
library("shiny")
library("googleVis")
library("dplyr")

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    d <- iris %>%
        group_by(Species) %>%
        summarise(ile=1e6*sum(Sepal.Length),
                  ile2=1e6*sum(Petal.Length))

    output$wyk <- renderGvis({
        gvisBarChart(d, xvar = "Species", yvar = c("ile", "ile2"),
                     options=list(legend="top", bar="{groupWidth:'90%'}", height=500))
    })
})
```

I'd be gratfull for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using [roles](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles), here's an example:

```
library("shiny")
library("googleVis")

d <- iris %>%
        group_by(Species) %>%
        summarise(ile=1e6*sum(Sepal.Length),
                  ile2=1e6*sum(Petal.Length))

d$ile.html.tooltip <- prettyNum(d$ile,big.mark = ",",scientific = F)
d$ile2.html.tooltip <- prettyNum(d$ile2,big.mark = ",",scientific = F)

ggvis_plot <- gvisBarChart(d, xvar = "Species", yvar = c("ile","ile.html.tooltip","ile2","ile2.html.tooltip"),
                     options=list(legend="top", bar="{groupWidth:'90%'}", height=500))

plot(ggvis_plot)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! After I got an answer for my first question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36125419/hover-style-of-label-in-googlevis) I tried to do the same. The only difference was the order of `yvar`. It would never have occured to me that this order is important. Amazing!